# netbeans 7.4 support for web application

Tags: java, web-services, netbeans

I want  to create a web application using NB 7.4. I read on the netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/quickstart-webapps.html

Setting Up a Web Application Project
Choose File > New Project (Ctrl-Shift-N) from the main menu. Under Categories, select Java Web. Under Projects, select Web Application then click Next. I do not have that as an option, I do not have a Java Web menu at all.

Can someone explain what I am missing

Comment: You probably didn't download the "JavaEE" pacakge. You can install the missing plugins using the plugin manager (Tools -> Plugins, then install those from the category "Java Web and EE".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you [downloaded](https://netbeans.org/downloads/) only the Java SE bundle of Netbeans. Either download Java EE bundle and install it or install the missing plugins via the "Tools / Plugins" menu (at least the "Java EE Base" plugin should be installed).